# Unable to retrieve the values from the database using Mule

Tags: stored-procedures, mule

I am trying to pass multiple query parameters through browser as

`http://localhost:8081/test?SourceQueue=mqinput&PayloadMsgId=11004a90Test0001-3`

My flow is as follows,
I am setting the query params to the payload using set payload transformer and then passing those values to the stored procedure. But I am not able to retrieve the values from the database. The payload is null after the database connector.

My **config xml** for the flow is as follows:

<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test"
doc:name="HTTP"/>

```
    <set-payload value="SourceQueue=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.SourceQueue],PayloadMsgId=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.PayloadMsgId]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]----------------before db" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{CALL E_Enquiry(:SourceQueue1,:PayloadMsgId1)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
        <db:in-param name="PayloadMsgId1" type="VARCHAR" value="#[payload.SourceQueue]"/>
        <db:in-param name="SourceQueue1" type="VARCHAR" value="#[payload.PayloadMsgId]"/>

    </db:stored-procedure>
    <logger message="#[payload]----output" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE E_Enquiry 
    (IN SourceQueue1 VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
     IN PayloadMsgId1 VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL) 
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN 
    DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CLIENT FOR 
        select PayloadMsgId,ExceptionId,EventSource,E_Message.InterfaceId,
            CreationTime,SourceProtocol,ErrorMessage,Severity,InterfaceName 
        from E_Message,E_Config
        where (SourceQueue=SourceQueue1 and PayloadMsgId=PayloadMsgId1); 
    open c1; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression :-

```
<set-payload value="SourceQueue=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.SourceQueue],PayloadMsgId=#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.PayloadMsgId]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

is not correct and you cannot achieve this by setting it into payload as the payload is a String format for now and not an Object.

The ideal solution will be using **variables** like the following :-

```
<set-variable variableName="SourceQueuevar" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.SourceQueue]" doc:name="Set SourceQueuevar"/>

 <set-variable variableName="PayloadMsgIdvar" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.PayloadMsgId]" doc:name="Set PayloadMsgIdvar"/>
```

Once this is set, you can easily use it anywhere, in you **SQL** or **logger** in the following expression like :-  `#[flowVars.SourceQueuevar] #[flowVars.PayloadMsgIdvar]`

Answer (score 0):

FlowVars are an opction, however you could also create a map easily using the following notation:

```
<set-payload value="#[['SourceQueue':message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.SourceQueue,'PayloadMsgId':message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.PayloadMsgId]]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

In this way you could access to the payload as an object (because it is a map). You can access to the payload value with an expression like this:

```
#[payload.SourceQueue]
```

or

```
#[payload.PayloadMsgId]
```